# Get category not include_in_menu or disabled

Tags: category, ce-1.9.0.1, menu

On my start page I have a product slider block where I show categories. Now I would like to have a category that is not in the menu but in the slide.

Problem is that if disable the category of set include_in_menu to false I don't get the category in the slider. Here is the slider query:

```
    $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
    $children = $_helper->getStoreCategories(false, true, false)
        ->addAttributeToSelect('product_slider')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('product_slider', array('neq' => ''))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('path', array('like' => "1/{$rootCategoryId}/%"))
        ->addOrderField('product_slider')
        ->addOrderField('name');
```

How do I get a catgory with `include_in_menu = false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PiTheNumber you cannot get   include_in_menu category using this code...
try this

```
 $category=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId());
$children = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection)->addAttributeToSelect('url_key')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('all_children')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
            ->addIdFilter($category->getChildren())
            ->setOrder('position', Varien_Db_Select::SQL_ASC)
            ->joinUrlRewrite()
            ->load();
```

Comment: If I replace `$_helper->getStoreCategories(false, true, false)` with `Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')` it works. Just found that out myself, too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
->addAttributeToFilter('include_in_menu', array('eq' => '0'))
```

Answer (score 0):

the definition of the fonction

```
getStoreCategories($sorted=false, $asCollection=false, $toLoad=true)
```

You want the method to return a collection that hasn't been loaded yet, thus the false, true, false arguments. 
Before you loop through the categories you want to make sure the image attribute is loaded as well, this is what the addAttributeToSelect('...') call is for.

Try with `getStoreCategories(false, true, true)`

Comment: This takes forever and fully loads all categories but not the ones with `include_in_menu = false`. But worth the try, thank you!